# How do I unzip a file with PPMd compression: I have the error "PPMd method not supported"

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, compression, zip

Ubuntu/Windows 7 user here,

I have a [zip file](http://notabs.org/primitivepolynomials/factor.zip) that I am trying to extract.  In windows I get an error.  In Ubuntu, the archive manager I get a  "PPMd method is not supported"

I read about '[e](http://martin.ankerl.com/2006/08/11/program-e-extract-any-archive/)', a ruby based exctractor in ubuntu, but I get the same result, "PPMd method is not supported"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to extract the file you linked using [**7-Zip**](http://www.7-zip.org/) without any problems.  I did this on Windows XP Pro 32-bit and also Windows 7 Pro 64-bit.  I have found that 7-Zip is a very good archiver.

Answer (score 0):

On Ubuntu, you could use the command line: `7z x factor.zip` which should support the PPMd method.  That file (factor.zip) read just fine on the zip utility (compressed folders) built in to Windows 7. Update: It read the list of files, but couldn't read the files themselves.